# Update object by id

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object looking something like

```
var_dump($object);

object(XX)#1836 (2) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(51)
  ["classes"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Now I wanted to add a `class` for the object where I know the ID and tried with

```
$object->ID[51]->classes[] = 'xxxxxxx';
```

But that doesn't work. How should I do to update object with ID? So after it would look like

```
object(XX)#1836 (2) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(51)
  ["classes"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(0) "xxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Comment: `$object->classes[] = 'xxxxxxx';`. `ID` is a property of the object, just like `classes`. `$object->ID` **returns** `51`.

Comment: @FelixKling but there are many. So I just want to update the one with `ID === 51` from somewhere. Or do I have to loop trough all of them?

Comment: Right now I only see one object. If there are many, where does `$object` come from? Over what do you want to iterate?

Comment: @FelixKling It is a function iterating trough all objects (or better calling every single object). Now object with ID 60 tells me to do something with 51 but I already past 51 ... know what I mean?

Comment: You need an index, the object as a whole is the value. If you're using a `foreach` iteration you could write `foreach ($objects as $key=>$object) {...}` where `$key` would be the index. But unless the `$key` is the same as `$object->ID` this will not work for you. Maybe you could post more code that could help make your structure clear. - As far as I know there is no way to filter objects by a specific property without looping over -

Comment: Sounds like you need an associative array that maps `id -> object`.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want only for `ID = 51`

```
if($object->ID == 51) {
  $object->classes[] = 'xxxx';
}
```

otherwise is just a matter of:

```
$object->classes[] = 'xxxx';
```

because `classes[]` is a member of `$object` like the `ID`.

Hope it helps! :D

Comment: Thank you, please read the comments above. Hope that makes my question more clear

Comment: so if you want to update only 51, then use the first statement... the one with if... or? Please tell me exactly what you want to achieve!

Comment: Seems to get to complicated, made a JS hack to get what I needed. Thought it's easy to use an object by its id..